# How long should I let a javascript function run before manually ending it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that has about 4 ajax requests in it. It typically takes less than a second to run. However, I'm working on the error handling now and was wondering. How long, in seconds, should I allow my javascript function to try to keep working until I manually cancel it and allow the user to try again?

Here's what the function in question looks like. (not everything is there, but it could potentially have (1000*5000*3)+(70)+(1000)+(6)+(2500) bytes being sent)

```
function saveChanges(bypassDeckSave){ 
  // bypassDeckSave = undefined - does not bypass
  showSavedNotification_check = 1;

  if(userid != 0){
    //values in database
    var subjectID = $('.lib_folder_id').val(),
        folderID = $('.lib_subject_id').val();

    if(subjectID == 0 || folderID == 0){//if database values null, ask for some
      console.log("db deck location not saved, asked for it");

      //values to set to 
      var setFolderID = $('.libDeckLocationModifierDiv .folders li.on').val(),
          setSubjectID = $('.libDeckLocationModifierDiv .subjects li.on').val();

      if(isNaN(setFolderID) || isNaN(setSubjectID) ||
          setFolderID == 0 || setSubjectID == 0)
      {
        openDeckLocationDiv();
        showSavedNotification_check = 0;
        return;
      }
    }
  }


  var deck_id = $('.deck_id').val();
  if(deck_id == 0){
    // create a new deck
    createDeckThenSave();
    return;
  }



  if(userid != 0){
    //values in database
    var subjectID = $('.lib_folder_id').val(),
        folderID = $('.lib_subject_id').val();

    if(subjectID == 0 || folderID == 0){//if database values null, ask for some
      //values to set to 
      saveDeckLocation();  
    }
  }



  // removes empty rows
  $('.editMain li').each(function(){
    var one   = $(this).find('.text1').val(),
        two   = $(this).find('.text2').val();
    if(one == "" && two == ""){
      //remove this row and remove value from updateSaveArray + add to delete array
      var currentval = $(this).val();
      var rowid = ".row_"+currentval;

      updateSaveArray = jQuery.grep(updateSaveArray, function(value) {
        return value != currentval;
      });
      $(rowid).remove();
      updateDeleteArray[updateDeleteArray.length] = currentval;
    }
  });



  if(bypassDeckSave == undefined){
    // save deck info to db
    var deckname  = $('.editDeckNameInput').val(),
        cardCount = $('.editMain li.mainLi:visible').length,

        deckTermLanguage = $('.selector.one select').val(),
        deckDefinitionLanguage = $('.selector.two select').val(),
        deckThirdBoxLanguage = $('.selector.three select').val(),

        deckDescription = $('.editMoreDeckOptionsDiv textarea').val();

    if($('.editMoreDeckOptionsSelector .onlyme').hasClass("on")){
      var viewPreferences = 1;
    }else{  
      var viewPreferences = 0; 
    }

    if($('.editUseThirdboxDiv').hasClass('on')){ var thirdbox = 1;
    }else{ var thirdbox = 2; }

    // console.log("deckInfoSave called");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/edit/deckInfoSave.php",
      data: { pDeckid: deck_id, pDeckname: deckname, pCardCount: cardCount, 
        pDeckTermLanguage: deckTermLanguage, pDeckDefinitionLanguage: deckDefinitionLanguage,
        pDeckThirdBoxLanguage: deckThirdBoxLanguage, pThirdbox: thirdbox,
        pDeckDescription: deckDescription, pViewPreferences: viewPreferences
      }
    })
    .done(function(data){
      // console.log(data);
      // decksaved = 1;
      saveDeckInfoHasFinished = 1;
    });
  }else{
    saveDeckInfoHasFinished = 1;
  }





  // prepares edited card array
  // gets all needed values and stores in holdSaveCardArray
  var holdSaveCardArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < updateSaveArray.length; ++i) {
    var currentCard_id    = updateSaveArray[i],
        rowidClass        = ".row_"+currentCard_id,
        text1val          = $(rowidClass+" .text1").val(),
        text2val          = $(rowidClass+" .text2").val(),
        text3val          = $(rowidClass+" .text3").val();
        cardOrder         = $(".editMain li.mainLi:visible").index($(rowidClass)) + 1;

    holdSaveCardArray[holdSaveCardArray.length] = {
      "card_id":        currentCard_id,
      "text1val":       text1val,
      "text2val":       text2val,
      "text3val":       text3val,
      "cardOrder":      cardOrder
    };

  }
  // console.log(print_r(holdSaveCardArray));

  // delete cards start
  // deletes any card with an id in updateDeleteArray
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/edit/deleteCards.php",
    data: { pDeck_id: deck_id, pDeleteArray: updateDeleteArray }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    // $('.temp').append(msg);
    updateDeleteArray = [];
    deleteCardsHasFinished = 1;
  }); 



  // save cards to database
  // loops through each card that had changes made to it

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/edit/saveCardsArray.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { pDeck_id: deck_id, pCardArray: holdSaveCardArray}
  }).done(function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
      var temp_id           = data[i]["temp_id"], // new id
          card_key          = data[i]["card_key"], // old id
          currentClassName  = 'row_'+temp_id,
          currentClass      = '.row_'+temp_id,
          nextClassName     = 'row_'+card_key;
      $(currentClass).val(card_key);
      $(currentClass).removeClass(currentClassName).addClass(nextClassName);
    }
    saveCardsHasFinished = 1;
  });
  updateSaveArray = [];




  // update order start  // uses li value
  updateOrderArray = [];
  $('.editMain').find(".mainLi").each(function(){
    var temp = $(this).val();
    updateOrderArray[updateOrderArray.length] = temp;
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/edit/orderCards.php",
    data: { pUpdateOrderArray: updateOrderArray }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    updateOrder = 0;
    updateOrdersHasFinished = 1;
  }); 


  closeLibDLM(); console.log("closeLibDLM1");
  changeSaveStudyButton(1);


} //saveChanges function end
```

Comment: I actually think this question is opinion oriented, so i am going to flag it as such.   It is subjective to determine what you should set your timeout to.

Comment: can't tell much from these code. it seems that you writing a card game of some sort. I would guess it shouldn't take too long to compute results. If it is taking long, you might want to revise your algorithm. Also depending on the nature of your app, the player wait time can vary, so Fallenreaper is correct to say this is opinionated.

Comment: Try not to download what appears to be over 10Mb. Mobile users will thank you.

Comment: @timo it would be really rare for somebody to actually use all 15 mbs, the average would be closer to 10k bytes...if that. But in anycase, I will set up some precautions for this. Thank you.

Comment: A Promise can't be stopped once you've send it. So if you have no limit. Set none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could totally set an arbitrary timeout, or even a timeout that *should* encompass everything finishing on time? But, what happens when it doesn't? What happens when it takes longer to finish?

At that point, you're going to be in quite a pickle. I did not thoroughly read your code, but I would **highly** advise trying to use a callback() or Promise to end your function. And, not set a timeout. - This is a cleaner solution in that things happen when you want them, and after some defined has happened. Time is a relative, and finicky attribute of our world (Einstein proved this =P) that would be best be used as your friend, and not your enemy.

The counter argument would be, well sometimes things just hang. And, that is totally valid. For that case, you could set a timeout for a long period of time. But, again, that is still a 'hacky' way to handle things. In this case, I would try to create some handling to detect errors, or timeouts. i.e you could periodically check the page for a status. You could check to see which events are in existence that you could hook into.

If you could share in what instances our program hangs, I could better suggest a solution. Otherwise this question may end up being opinionated based on coding styles.

Hope this helps in some regard :)

Answer (score 1):

I've worked in the Aerospace Aviation Industry and have asked a similar question when working with Microcontrollers. It seems you are looking for an appropriate timeout value based on calculation, but this may not be necessary in your case. Often times timeout values are more or less arbitrary. If your function executes in an average of roughly 1 second, maybe your timeout value should be set to 3 seconds. You should come to a conclusion based on testing.

Comment: I have done my fair share of embedded programming and I feel that use case is relatively similar. Even in an embedded world, I'd try to use to use some sort of feedback/IO to determine when to continue execution. - Granted that feedback/IO may be harder to gather in the real world than in a website